# More than one page in Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I am new on Bootstrap and googled for one week now, but I didnt find what I want or something in the right direction.
I want to build a website with a navbar (no problem) and I want to click in the navbar and the content will shown.
Problem: I have to copy in every HTML-Page the Menu and if I create a new page I have to update the Menu on every page.
My ideas:

1. have a navbar and load via AJAX the specific content (special id in the link)?
2. build a PHP script, which is getting a GET-variable and create the html-document (URLs with mod-rewrite)
3. other ideas

I am really sorry, I am more looking for a "concept" or something, I cant imagine that I am the only person with such a problem.
Would be awesome, if you could give me some advices or google keywords for searching.

I tried google keywords like "bootstrap navbar load div ajax"

Comment: in my opinion, the easiest way would be to have a php file containing the nav bar html that you then `include`/`require` at the top of every page (if each page has its own source file).

Comment: So many ways to do this. Start with Server Side Includes.

Comment: there are so many ways to do this. first of all you have to design web app or mobile app. then for client side what you are using  AngularJS or something else. It's not difficult you can achieve it.

Comment: I usually use the concept of dynamically loading content with ajax (using jquery).

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this. 
A few of them are already mentioned in the comments.

But in my opinion the cleanest way is to use a template engine (e.g. Twig). With a template engine you can build a main template for the main parts which have to be shown on every page (header, footer, navbar).  For the dynamic / page specific content you have separate templates which extend the main template.

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS was a keyword I needed, I found a tutorial showing what I want:
https://scotch.io/tutorials/single-page-apps-with-angularjs-routing-and-templating

Thank you!